# Get JSON-Object Name as String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

How do I get the object *muxEnviroments* as String? I want to analyze and compare to check what type of content I have to expect.

`console.log(obj)` shows me the whole object.
My goal is something like that:

```
jsonObjectName = obj;
if(jsonObjectName =='muxEnviroments'){do the stuff...}
```

But how to get the Name 'muxEnviroments' as string?

```
{
    "muxEnviroments": [
        {
            "primaryTransmitterName": "sfu5",
            "primaryTransmitterIp": "10.7.50.1"
        },
        {
            "primaryTransmitterName": "sfu1",
            "primaryTransmitterIp": "10.7.50.4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```html
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('muxEnviroments')) {do the stuff...}
```

Comment: I've dropped my answer. I don't know why I prefered `Object.keys` over `Object.hasOwnProperty`

Comment: You're right, this one is better. Deleted my answer.